# How can I show the computed compiler flags for a clang invocation?

Tags: clang, llvm

For example, when I run `clang` with `clang ... -Wno-error -Werror`, I don't want to it to show `-Wno-error`, since it's being overridden. I could use `-v` or `-###` to print out what the driver's executing, but that doesn't help because it still shows `-Wno-error -Werror` at the end. How might I show the computed compiler flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-cc1` flag `-compiler-options-dump` appears to be the best option at the moment.